# No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 3 routes that are in my routing table.  The second route in the table is as follows based on the my code in the AreaRegistration class:

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "Contests_default", 
            "Contests/{danceStyle}/{danceStyleID}/{competition}/{competitionID}/{division}/{divisionID}",
            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Contest", action = "Index",
                  danceStyle = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  competition = UrlParameter.Optional,
                  division = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

however when I navigate to a URL such as:
`http:localhost/Contests/WCS/5/JackandJill/1/Advanced/4'

I receive the exception listed in the title.  Any advice?

Comment: Do you have a controller named Contest and an Action named Index? Are they in an area? What is the area? Can you show both controller and the full Area regisration class, as well as your other route table related code?

Comment: I Added a new area named "Contests", and simple copied you code to register the area and it worked liked a charm. using the url you specified 'http:localhost/Contests/WCS/5/JackandJill/1/Advanced/4', please share your other routes.tx